# Using SQL Server how can I query across three separate tables outer joining on a common column between all three of them?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to achieve the following output from the given structure. I've included my attempt at this query but it has a fundamental problem. Across millions of records using common dates loses efficiency because it will be querying the *breakfasts* table (for instance) for dates that don't exist in the breakfasts table.

Desired output:

```
/*
DESIRED OUTPUT
Date            BreakfastAttendees      LunchAttendees              DinnerAttendees
2016-01-01  10                      10                          10
2016-02-01  NULL                    10                          10
2016-03-01  NULL                    NULL                        10
*/
```

Structure

```
declare @breakfasts table(Date datetime, Attendees int);
declare @lunches table(Date datetime, Attendees int);
declare @dinners table(Date datetime, Attendees int);

insert into @breakfasts values('01/01/2016',10);

insert into @lunches values('01/01/2016',10);
insert into @lunches values('02/01/2016',10);

insert into @dinners values('01/01/2016',10);
insert into @dinners values('02/01/2016',10);
insert into @dinners values('03/01/2016',10);
```

**Attempt**

```
;With CommonDates_cte as 
(
    select distinct Date
    from @breakfasts

    union

    select distinct Date
    from @lunches

    union

    select distinct Date
    from @dinners
)
select 
    cte.Date, BreakfastAttendees, LunchAttendees, DinnerAttendees
from 
    CommonDates_cte cte
cross apply 
    (select 
         SUM(Attendees) AS BreakfastAttendees
     from @breakfasts b
     where b.Date = cte.Date) b
cross apply 
    (select 
         SUM(Attendees) AS LunchAttendees
     from @lunches l
     where l.Date = cte.Date) l
cross apply 
    (select 
         SUM(Attendees) AS DinnerAttendees
     from @dinners d
     where d.Date = cte.Date) d
```

Comment: Do you really need to sum?  Can date duplicate in a table?

Comment: You don't need the `DISTINCT` on your `UNION` -- `UNION` by definition will remove duplicate values from the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this assumes date can repeat
if not there are better answers

```
;With CommonDates_cte as (
    select Date
         , Attendees as BreakfastAttendees 
         , 0         as LunchAttendees 
         , 0         as DinnerAttendees
    from @breakfasts   
    union all 
    select Date
         , 0         as BreakfastAttendees 
         , Attendees as LunchAttendees 
         , 0         as DinnerAttendees
    from @lunches
    union all 
    select Date
         , 0         as BreakfastAttendees 
         , 0         as LunchAttendees 
         , Attendees as DinnerAttendees 
    from @dinners
)
select date, sum(BreakfastAttendees), sum(LunchAttendees), sum(DinnerAttendees)
from CommonDates_cte 
group by date
```

or

```
;With CommonDates_cteB as (
        select Date, sum(Attendees)  
        from @breakfasts 
        group by Date )
    , CommonDates_cteL as (
        select Date, sum(Attendees)  
        from @lunches
        group by Date ) 
    , CommonDates_cteD as (
        select Date, sum(Attendees)  
        from @dinners
        group by Date )
SELECT COALESCE(b.[Date], l.[Date], d.[Date]),
       b.Attendees AS BreakfastAttendees,
       l.Attendees AS LunchAttendees,
       d.Attendees AS DinnerfastAttendees
FROM      CommonDates_cteB AS b
FULL JOIN CommonDates_cteL AS l ON l.[Date] = b.[Date]
FULL JOIN CommonDates_cteD AS d ON d.[Date] = b.[Date]
```

if date does not repeat then

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.[Date], l.[Date], d.[Date]),
       b.Attendees AS BreakfastAttendees,
       l.Attendees AS LunchAttendees,
       d.Attendees AS DinnerfastAttendees
FROM      @breakfasts AS b
FULL JOIN @lunches    AS l ON l.[Date] = b.[Date]
FULL JOIN @dinners    AS d ON d.[Date] = b.[Date]
```

Comment: The top version is working well for me and leaves a nice clean query for the final output select.  I think 'Union All' would be slightly faster without altering the results.   I'll experiment some more but credit this as the solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can give this query a try:

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.[Date], l.[Date], d.[Date]),
       SUM(b.Attendees) AS BreakfastAttendees,
       SUM(l.Attendees) AS LunchAttendees,
       SUM(d.Attendees) AS DinnerfastAttendees
FROM @breakfasts AS b
FULL JOIN @lunches AS l ON b.[Date] = l.[Date]
FULL JOIN @dinners AS d ON d.[Date] = l.[Date]
GROUP BY COALESCE(b.[Date], l.[Date], d.[Date])
```

The query assumes that there is only a single record for any given date for all three tables.

Comment: Problem here is a duplicate date in one will cause duplicates in others and result in incorrect sum.

Comment: @PhilipKelley Yes your are right, `COALESCE` takes a variable number of argmunents. Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to assume that there is only a single record for any given date for all three tables then you don't need the group by or sum.

Comment: This is an interesting approach and I tried it out.  It did not run as fast as @Paparazzi's approach.